# Store entries(custom pojo) in sorted order and retrieve entries around an entry

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to simulate a game board where multiple players can submit their game scores.

The POJO viz. Entry.java represents an entry in the leaderboard. **Note the overriden equals() method**.

> Position is the position in the leaderboard, 1 being the user with the
>   highest score

```
public class Entry {

private String uid;
private int score;
private int position;

public Entry(String uid, int score) {

    this.uid = uid;
    this.score = score;

}

public Entry() {

}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + score;
    result = prime * result + ((uid == null) ? 0 : uid.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Entry other = (Entry) obj;
    if (score != other.score)
        return false;
    if (uid == null) {
        if (other.uid != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!uid.equals(other.uid))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entry [uid=" + uid + ", score=" + score + ", position=" + position + "]";
}
```

}

The GameBoard class has a couple of methods :

- submitScore(String uid, int score)
  Each player calls this method to submit his score to the game board. There is only one entry per player/user, hence, if a player calls this method multiple times, his latest score is stored
- getLeaderBoard(String uid)

> If the user is in the leaderboard, returns max two entries that have
>   larger score than the user (the users that are immediately above the
>   user in the leaderboard), the user’s own entry and max two entries
>   that are immediately after the user in the leaderboard

e.g:

```
The leader board is :
Entry [uid=user1, score=14, position=1]
Entry [uid=user2, score=8, position=2]
Entry [uid=user3, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]

For user5, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user3, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]

For user4, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user1, score=14, position=1]
Entry [uid=user2, score=8, position=2]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]

For user6, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]

For user7, entries returned should be :

Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]
```

I decided to use HashMap for the leader board.

```
public class GameDefault {

    private Map<String, Entry> leaderBoardUserEntryMap;

    {
        leaderBoardUserEntryMap = new HashMap<>();
    }


    public void submitScore(String uid, int score) {

        Entry newEntry = new Entry(uid, score);
        leaderBoardUserEntryMap.put(uid, newEntry);
    }

    public List<Entry> getLeaderBoard(String uid) {

        if (!leaderBoardUserEntryMap.containsKey(uid))
            return Collections.emptyList();

        List<Entry> entriesOptionOne = leaderBoardUserEntryMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getScore, Integer::compare).reversed()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("---------Current leader board---------");
        entriesOptionOne.forEach(System.out::println);

        if (entriesOptionOne != null && !entriesOptionOne.isEmpty()) {
            int indexOfUserEntry = entriesOptionOne.indexOf(leaderBoardUserEntryMap.get(uid));
            return CollectionUtil.getSubList(entriesOptionOne, indexOfUserEntry - 2, indexOfUserEntry + 3);
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}
```

Now, there are following issues and concerns :

- The program doesn't return proper entries since I am using indexes and subList, what is required is like 'higherKey(key)' & 'lowerKey(key)' in TreeMap
- When(ideally, during submitScore()) and how shall the 'position' be calculated.Though it's used for keys, I was wondering if Map.compute() can help in any way !
- Since the leader board can have even a million entries, sorting and then retrieving on every call to getLeaderBoard() seems infeasible. I tried using a a SortedMap of Entry-Uid(TreeMap) but the `equals()` contract in the `SortedMap` doc is a challenge

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the
>   sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See the
>   Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition
>   of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is
>   defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs
>   all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two
>   keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of
>   the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a tree map is well-defined even
>   if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Map interface.

Comment: I've actually seen this yesterday and forgot to ask why can't you store them in `TreeMap<Entry, String>` where they are sorted according to your `compareTo`. You could get same entries according to that and thus I would switch to `TreeMultimap` that exists in guava. And yes sorting on each `get` is bad.

Comment: @Eugene I tried TreeMap as I thought it's cleaner(possibly, more efficient) but the Comparator for the score and the Entry.equals() don't go hand-in-hand, causing failure. Can you help here ?

Comment: I don't even see you overriding `compareTo` in Entry at all, what do you mean?

Comment: I have the failing code using the TreeMap, how shall I share that with you? Another question for discussing that code would be confusing and I don't know how to move this conversation to a chat ...

Comment: I don't actually want that code shared with me - you can post it here. It is a simple `compareTo` method that you have to implement that has to be consistent with equals/hashcode

Comment: a good point to move to a `Tree` structure is that if you have Integer.MAX_VALUE entries, search time will be a max of 32 steps to find your entry.

Comment: Posted a new question with my failing TreeMap code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198930/store-entries-in-sorted-order-and-retrieve-entries-around-an-entry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154347/discussion-between-kaliyug-antagonist-and-eugene).