# Store entries in sorted order and retrieve entries around an entry

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying to simulate a game board where multiple players can submit their game scores.

The POJO viz. Entry.java represents an entry in the leaderboard. **Note the overriden equals() method**.

> Position is the position in the leaderboard, 1 being the user with the
>   highest score

```
public class EntryTreeMapOption {

private String uid;
private int score;
private int position;

public EntryTreeMapOption(String uid, int score) {

    this.uid = uid;
    this.score = score;

}

public EntryTreeMapOption() {

}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((uid == null) ? 0 : uid.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EntryTreeMapOption other = (EntryTreeMapOption) obj;
    if (uid == null) {
        if (other.uid != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!uid.equals(other.uid))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entry [uid=" + uid + ", score=" + score + ", position=" + position + "]";
}}
```

The GameBoard class has a couple of methods :

- submitScore(String uid, int score) Each player calls this method to submit his score to the game board. There is only one entry per player/user, hence, if a player calls this method multiple times, his latest score is stored
- getLeaderBoard(String uid)

> If the user is in the leaderboard, returns max two entries that have
>   larger score than the user (the users that are immediately above the
>   user in the leaderboard), the user’s own entry and max two entries
>   that are immediately after the user in the leaderboard

e.g:

```
The leader board is :
Entry [uid=user1, score=14, position=1]
Entry [uid=user2, score=8, position=2]
Entry [uid=user3, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]

For user5, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user3, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]

For user4, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user1, score=14, position=1]
Entry [uid=user2, score=8, position=2]
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]

For user6, entries returned should be :
Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user6, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]

For user7, entries returned should be :

Entry [uid=user4, score=7, position=3]
Entry [uid=user5, score=4, position=4]
Entry [uid=user7, score=3, position=5]
Entry [uid=user8, score=1, position=6]
```

My initial approach was to use a TreeMap, the alternative is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197299/store-entriescustom-pojo-in-sorted-order-and-retrieve-entries-around-an-entry).

```
public class GameDefault2 {

    private TreeMap<EntryMapOption, String> leaderBoardEntryUserMap;

    {

        leaderBoardEntryUserMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(EntryTreeMapOption::getScore).reversed()
            .thenComparing(EntryTreeMapOption::getUid));
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScore(String uid, int score) {

        EntryMapOption newEntry = new EntryMapOption(uid, score);
        leaderBoardEntryUserMap.put(newEntry, uid);

    }

    @Override
    public List<EntryMapOption> getLeaderBoard(String uid) {

        System.out.println("---------Current leader board---------");
        leaderBoardEntryUserMap.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);

        List<EntryMapOption> userEntryList = leaderBoardEntryUserMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> uid.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey().getUid())).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (userEntryList == null || userEntryList.isEmpty())
            return Collections.emptyList();

        // Incomplete and error prone
        EntryMapOption userEntry = userEntryList.get(0);

        List<EntryMapOption> entriesOptionTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        entriesOptionTwo.add(leaderBoardEntryUserMap.higherKey(userEntry));
        entriesOptionTwo.add(userEntry);
        entriesOptionTwo.add(leaderBoardEntryUserMap.lowerKey(userEntry));

        return entriesOptionTwo;

    }

}
```

The issues with the above code :

- When(ideally, during submitScore()) and how shall the 'position' be calculated. Though it's used for keys, I was wondering if Map.compute() can help in any way !
- Check the code below '// Incomplete and error prone' comment
  While 'higherKey()' and 'lowerKey()' come handy, I am unsure how to use them to pick a fixed number of entries below and above a particular entry

*****Edit-1******
@Holger's fix solved the following issue

- I am unable to figure out how to fix the inconsistency between equals() and compare(). This is causing missing entries

Comment: `Comparator.comparingInt(EntryMapOption::getScore).reversed().thenComparingInt( EntryMapOption::getUid)`…

Comment: @Holger Solved the first problem :)
Updating the original comparator code.

Comment: You must not modify attributes of a key that affect its lookup logic, i.e. hash code in case of `HashMap` or the sort property in case of a `TreeMap`. If it has a natural order, it must not change in both cases. You’ll have to remove first and re-add after the modification or perform a bulk operation creating a new `Map`. Regarding `higherKey` and `lowerKey`, it’s not clear where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

## Potential issue with the map

Your equals method is based upon the ID, but your compare method is based on the score, which will cause issues, from the JavaDoc.

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.

The problem is that the compare method will take the search in the wrong direction, as it ordering on a different property.

In your case this may be less of an issue, although you could have 2 equal objects which do not have the same score, leading to future issues.

## Potential issue using TreeMap

Changing the score while the item is in the tree may also cause issue, so you may have to remove the item each time their score changes, and re-add them.

## Working code

An example of the process working would be this

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {

  static class Example {
    final int id;
    final int score;

    Example(int id, int score) {
      this.id = id;
      this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (!(obj instanceof Example)) {
        return false;
      }
      final Example other = (Example) obj;
      return other.id == id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return id;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return id + " scored " + score;
    }

    public int getScore() {
      return score;
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    Example a = new Example(1, 10);
    Example b = new Example(2, 30);
    Example c = new Example(3, 1);
    Example d = new Example(4, 10);

    TreeMap<Example, Integer> x = new TreeMap<Example, Integer>(Comparator.comparingInt(Example::getScore).thenComparing(Example::getId));

    x.put(a, a.getScore());
    x.put(b, b.getScore());
    x.put(c, c.getScore());
    x.put(d, d.getScore());

    final Example h2 = x.higherKey(a);
    final Example h1 = h2 == null ? null : x.higherKey(h2);

    final Example l1 = x.lowerKey(a);
    final Example l2 = l1 == null ? null : x.lowerKey(l1);

    System.out.println(h1);
    System.out.println(h2);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(l1);
    System.out.println(l2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, all I was missing is the proper way to use the Comparator in the TreeMap constructor, now it's fixed

Comment: So are you suggesting that TreeMap isn't the way? Which data structure would help here, from correctness and performance perspectives ?

Comment: TreeMap does work, but it would need to be in the form of my example code, as then the tree would be balanced by the scores, making lookups faster, but changed scores **need** to be removed and readded, else there will be issues

Comment: Except the removal of 'reversed', I guess your example code is same as my original one(equals() using only uid is inconsistent with comparator using uid and score) - can you add the snippet which you mentioned ' but changed scores need to be removed and readded, else there will be issues' ?

Comment: My code goes from Example to score, rather than example to String (the ID). The removal would be `x.remove(item)` followed by `x.put(item, item.score)`

Comment: I doubt this works, duplicates will get added in the Map e.g: Example(1, 10) and Example(1, 4) both will be added, also, it's unclear how will this help in setting the position field(that needs to be included in Example, though it's not used for comparing or equality)